# Uses of Bash scripting in C / C++ programming projects.

Tags: bash, project

In what ways are scripting languages (especially bash) is used to manage large C++/C programming projects?

It will be helpful if someone can list some clever uses of scripts in their programming projects at automating certain tasks.

Comment: You can embed Python into C++.

Comment: Build systems can be extremely complex, but i would not use bash anymore for anything except very small non critical shortcut scripts to run commands. Everything else should be done with modern script languages or build solutions.

Comment: *"In what ways are..."* suggests a make-a-list question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally used shell scripting to invoke my program multiple times for different inputs, for loading the necessary modules before I try to run my program, for automatic graph plotting with gnuplot etc. When I was working on huge clusters I also found a script very useful when I had to set/query some runtime settings to launch my tasks on the cluster. I always use GNU Make to build my programs, but if you have extremely small non-critical projects, you can use scripts to even build your code.

I am sure that there are a lot of other innovative ways to use bash scripts, but whatever I just said is from the perspective of an ordinary developer who does a lot of (almost) mundane stuff everyday. And bash scripts have made my life a lot easier, to say the least.